# How to mount drive without partition table?

Tags: partitioning, mount, cloud

I have an Ubuntu 10.4 slice on RackspaceCloud that is no longer responding after trying to upgrade to 11.10. I used their "Rescue Mode" to boot another slice with access to my old server, which gives me the following information on my main partition when I use fdisk -l:

> root@server:~# fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/xvdb: 81.6 GB, 81604378624 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9921 cylinders, total 159383552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

When I try and mount this, it won't let me without fixing this issue:

> root@server:~# mount /dev/xvdb /mnt 
>   mount: you must specify the filesystem type

I'm guessing that the lack of a partition table is why I can't boot into the server -- is there a way to fix this or at least get access to the data on this disk?

**UPDATE:**

Just tried again with a fresh rescue instance and got a little closer with:

```
root@server:/var/log# mount /dev/xvdb /mnt
root@server:/var/log# cd /mnt
root@server:/mnt# ls -l
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 2012-06-17 14:33 lost+found
```

The lost+found folder is all that is in the newly mounted drive which I suspect is because of the missing partition table again.

I'm new at working with partitions on ubuntu, so I may be making an obvious mistake -- any resource suggestions or other tricks greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lack of a partition table is not the issue.  You appear to have an entirely blank drive in the first instance, and in the second, you have a freshly formatted one.  Perhaps your xen configuration is pointing the drive to the wrong location?